# Autofit text in a rectangle on android

Tags: android, text, view, canvas

I'm using a view and drawing over a bitmap some text,it does not have a fixed size, so I want the text to fit the rectangle I define and if it's needed split the string in some lines.
I don't know how to do it in android.
I found one solution using StaticLayout, but doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
Bitmap arBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ar_bitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(arBitmap ,bitmapPos,20,  null);ll);
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
canvas.drawText(textToDisplay,textPos , 35, paint);
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds